# Flash web sites

Tags: flash

I want to see how a flash web site is made, is there a way to see the AS3 code ?

Answer (score 0):

Just read tutorials. In google first link with "flash ac3 website" gives fine tutorial: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/basicwebsite/ To see "any" websites AC3 code you have to decompile flash and still no one knows if it wont be affected by decompiler. So just stick to the tutorials. Good source for it is: http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/Flash/1

Answer (score 0):

If the .swf was published from Adobe Flash Builder then it's possible that the "enable view source" checkbox was checked, in which case you can right-click and go to "view source" on the .swf.

That said, it's highly unlikely that any high-caliber .swf's deployed in production environments are going to leave that option enabled because it would allow anyone to see how the project works and potentially cause problems.

One of the advantages of using Flash over HTML is that it's difficult for someone to get a sense of how you coded the project. You COULD decompile the .swf, but that's not always a fun time.

Short answer: no, there's generally no easy way to "view source" on a piece of Flash work that you like. But if there is something you like and want a high-level answer to "how would I get started building something like this", ask and someone may have some insight for you!

Cheers, and I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I think I will just do the tuts, thanks for the link,I'm looking for any sites that have Acionscript projects done with Flex/Flashbuilder but there doesn't seem to be any really :(

Comment: http://www.gotoandlearn.com has lots of AS3 tutorials, he uses Flash Builder in some of those I suspect. Also, if you want a deeper emphasis on Flex, google "Flex in a week" and there's a whole tutorial series provided by Adobe.